# The correct way to parse facebook feed

Tags: php, facebook

I would like to parse one newest feed from one page by PHP.

As I readed, FB rejected curl/fopen and another ways to parse some data.
Instead of this i should use FB API, ok i'll take PHP SDK.

```
$info = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed?access_token={some_access_token}'));
```

Fine, it return me feeds from cocacola page, but it require valid access token.
To get access token user should at least once authorize my app, right?

Reuire autorize from user is not the best idea in this website, so maybe someone know the better way to get just one (newest) feed?

Comment: Do you just need feeds of 'public' pages?

Comment: yes, like this  
https://facebook.com/cocacola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to access the feed of a public page is an application access token for your application, you don't need a user's access token. If you don't have an application you must first set one up at http://developers.facebook.com/apps.

Once you have an app set up on Facebook, you can get an application access token here (replace your app ID and secret ID with the values found on the Facebook app page):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<YOUR_APP_ID>&client_secret=<YOUR_APP_SECRET>&grant_type=client_credentials
```

You can use this in your call to the feed page, as per the link in your question.

Comment: Maybe you have idea how to cut the count of feeds in request?
because it return me 1 page of results (with about 19 feeds as i remembered). i need only one, it's not critical, but maybe request will be done faster. i tried something like &count=1 , but it not helps

Comment: It's `&limit=1`, details here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/